# Как перевернуть строку в pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датасет с колонкой Time
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h1S5ubz2T2mwPaK4WAzrnbJqmV8Ui9Ei

### Как в столбце Time вместо '2017.01.07' сделать '07.01.2017', то есть перевернуть строку?

Исходник

```
         Time   Con     y   Sum
0   2017.01.07  337.0   0   0.0
1   2017.03.07  334.0   3   77.4
2   2017.04.07  303.0   31  863.4
3   2017.05.07  253.0   50  1370.0
4   2017.06.07  250.0   3   82.2
... ... ... ... ...
541 2019.12.25  87.0    8   232.0
542 2019.12.26  85.0    2   54.0
543 2019.12.30  71.0    14  300.0
544 2020.09.01  25.0    46  1334.0
545 2020.10.01  23.0    2   38.0
```

---

После to_datetime что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

проще всего спарсить этот столбец в `datetime64` и потом преобразовать это в строку нужного вам формата:

```
col = "date_col_name"
df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], errors="coerse")

df[col] = df[col].dt.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
```

PS исходный и целевой формат даты распространяются еа весь dataset.Судя по комментарию, у вас исходные данные уже "поломаны" и чинить их надо в том месте где они ломаются. Делать это на более поздних этапах - слишком трудоемкая задача.

PPS на будущее - если вы храните временные данные в текстовом виде (например в CSV), то всегда сохраняйте временные данные в формате `yyyy-mm-dd`. Преимущества данного формата:

1. никогда не будет путаницы с форматами;
2. такие данные можно **правильно** сортировать как строки
3. это формат даты по умолчанию в Python, т.е. парсить такие данные можно не указывая формат даты

Comment: Если с to_datetime сбивается дата 544-545 строки должны быть январями, а они сентябри-октябри(скриншот прилагаю)

Comment: @svil, вы можете выложить датасет в __свободный__ доступ? (чтобы отвечающие на вопрос не "светили" свой email)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h1S5ubz2T2mwPaK4WAzrnbJqmV8Ui9Ei

Comment: В вопросе вы указали, что исходные данные в формате `2017.01.07`, а на картинке `01.09.2020` - кому верить? ;)

Comment: Я имею в виду сбивается дата

Comment: Видите 542-543 строки за декабрь некорректно выглядят

Comment: 30.12.2019 сконвертировалось - а должно быть 12.30.2019, а примеры 2017.01.07 - это 1 июля 2017 - он должен быть '07.01.2017, пример 01.09.2020 - это 544 запись сконвертированная в датасете после применения to_datetime, потому что выше 30.12.2019, а должна быть 12.30.2019

Comment: Google Drive - `"You need permission. Want in? Ask for access,..."` для того, чтобы дать осмысленный ответ, надо видеть в каком формате у вас исходные данные. В каком формате вы хотите получить данные в итоге? `07.01.2017` из вопроса - это 7е января или 1е июля?

Comment: Сейча повторно датасет переоткрою в доступ

Comment: @svil, а не проще привести 3-5 первых строк исходного файла в виде текста прямо в теле вопроса и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h1S5ubz2T2mwPaK4WAzrnbJqmV8Ui9Ei/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Сейчас добавлю 3-5 строк исходника

Comment: Сам датасет некорректный, наверно его никак не исправить.

Comment: @svil, по какому критерию вы определяете некорректные записи?

Comment: Логически не может быть так 2019.12.26 2019.12.30  2020.09.01  2020.10.01 - это четыре поседние записи декабрь декабрь(2019) сентябрь октябрь(2020)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107030/discussion-between-maxu-and-svil).